# float problems on live server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to make a registration form, that should calculate 2 fields, and put the answer into a Db. This works flawlessly on localhost, but when I copy the files over to the server and try it live it fails.

[image: The error message that comes up when running from the server.]

The following code :

```
    var l = Convert.ToSingle(honorarList.Text);
    var m = Convert.ToSingle(bomList.Text);
    var s = l + m;

    var i = Convert.ToSingle(km.Text);
    var j = Convert.ToSingle(kmSatsList.Text);
    var k = i * j;
    kmGodt.Text = " " + k;

    var z = s + k;
    totalSum.Text = " " + z;
```

I have removed the SQL insert statement.

SQL structure:

[image: Structure I have in MS-SQL]

Comment: The server's locale is different, making SQL expect a different decimal separator. Try searching. You also shouldn't use string concatenation to build queries, if you use parameterized queries it'll work just fine.

Comment: The code in the question is completely irrelevant to the problem. The problem is with the way you execute SQL, by concatenating values into a SQL statement, not with the posted code.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems I guess, both related to each other.

1. Your language settings are different on the server. A solution to that would be to provide the culture to the `Convert.ToSingle` method:

   ```
   Convert.ToSingle(km.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   ```

   You are also passing that variable as a string, which you shouldn't do to begin with.
2. The worst problem you have is that you are not using parameterized queries. You are now vulnerable to SQL injection. You have to rewrite your code to use parameters instead of constructing the SQL yourself. That will fix your issue too since the ADO.NET provider will convert the `float` itself.